# Split uplink and downlink between interfaces with openvswitch

Tags: networking, openflow, openvswitch

I have one or more virtual machines on Debian host and two physical eth interfaces. I want to split bandwidth between eths (both for downlink and one for uplink). Is it possible with openvswitch and openflow?

Comment: Stackoverflow is a place to ask/answer programming questions. This is not a programming-related question.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that it should be possible with OVS and OpenFlow. With OVS you can connect your VM's virtual ports and the server's physical interfaces.

Without thinking too much, you can load balancing the traffic by:

1. Installing a flow to direct any VM packet to your uplink port. This flow should rewrite the src IP and MAC as the ones from the downlink interface, so that it will look like it is being sent through that port.
2. Keep in mind that you might take your virtual ports configuration into account, and that you need some kind of mapping (something like NAT), to get the packets correctly returned to its respective VM. You can take a look in a [NAT implementation](https://github.com/John-Lin/nat/blob/master/snat.py), for the [Ryu controller](https://osrg.github.io/ryu/), to get some inspiration.